# How can we use the datepicker to change the date format with vee-validate V4 library

Tags: date, datepicker, vuejs3, date-format, vee-validate

Currently I am using the vee-validate v4 library to validate all my form inputs, How can I use the datepicker with vee-validate to change the date format ? I am using schema format to validate the fields like `:validation-schema="schema"` And I have to change the date format to be mm/dd/yyyy

```
           <Form class="row g-3" :validation-schema="schema" @submit="submit($event)" v-slot="{ errors }">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="inputdate" class="form-label"
                  >Expiration Date<span class="required-field"></span></label>
                <Field
                  name="ExpiryDate"
                  type="date"
                  v-model="ExpiryDate"
                  placeholder="Enter date"
                  class="form-control"
                  id="inputdate"
                  :class="{ 'is-invalid': errors.ExpiryDate }"
                />
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  {{ errors.ExpiryDate }}
                </div>
              </div>
          </Form>
```

Comment: That is how an HTML `input[type=date]` works, it internally stores the value in a certain format and only shows it differently: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to achieve the validation of datepicker through vee-validate, you will have to handle it manually through code.